# Showing a taskbar baloon tip popup message in a remote computer's desktop in the LAN

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming, popup, popupwindow

Hope you all have noticed the messages that appears on the desktop as a pop up near the windows taskbar; in situations when New Windows Updates are available, when a print job is sent to a printer etc.

I want to send a message to another computer in my LAN, and it should appear as a popup near taskbar as I explained above.

Is there anyway I could achieve this? best if I could do that through c#.

All I understand is that, we can't do such influence to another computer as a normal user, may be my program should tell my windows to send a message to the remote computer's windows (system) to show the message that way as coming through it's system.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no black magic available here.  You actually need to run a program on the remote machine to get that balloon.  Easy to do with the NotifyIcon class.  Sending a message to that program is simple enough with TcpListener and TcpClient.

Comment: There are ways even to install stuff without any client running on the remote computer while the user on that remote computer can't see anything other than HDD activity, so can't call that black magic. Is there anyway to ask the remote OS to start a TCPListen through local OS?

Comment: Yes, it has been done.  The Conflicker virus for example.  This is not the right web site.